# STL stack with elements of array

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl, stack

Im new to c++. I want to create a stack with arrays. Im using STL. I need to store two values in an array and then push/pop to stack
in python i will simply do:

```
s = Stack()
s.push((1,"item"))
s.push((3,"item"))
```

so there will be two tuples in stack (1,"item"), (3,"item)

I tried something like this in c++, but its wrong:

```
stack<string, list<string> > exampleStack;
string test[2] = {"wtf","lol"};
exampleStack.push(dd);
```

Comment: You need to push elements on to the stack that are always 2 number of items or n number of items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to store only **two** values of different datatypes, you can use `std::pair`.

1. Create a `stack<pair<int,string> >`.
2. To push the `pair<int,string>` into the stack, use `push()` function and the `make_pair` function to make a pair for the `push()` function.

Code:

```
stack<pair<int,string> > s;
s.push(make_pair(1,string("item")));
s.push(make_pair(3,string("item")));
```

EDIT: (Thanks to @imlyc)

If you enable the `-std=c++11` flag when compiling with `g++`, you can replace

```
s.push(make_pair(1,string("item")));
```

with

```
s.push({1,"item"});
```

Comment: Or just simply using `s.push({1, "abc"});`

Answer (score 0):

```
stack<list<string> > exampleStack;

list<string> l1 = list<string>;
l1.push_back("aaa");
l1.push_back("bbb");
exampleStack.push(l1);

list<string> l2 = list<string>;
l2.push_back("ddddd");
l2.push_back("eeeee");
exampleStack.push(l2);
```